# Android App Consent Form Using Google's Consent SDK not Showing at All

Tags: gdprconsentform, ccpa, admob-cookieconsent

My Android app is ready to publish, but it currently doesn't ask for user consent before loading personalized ads through a consent form. It does have a privacy and cookie policy. I downloaded the Consent SDK and imported it in the Main Activity of my app. The consentform.html doesn't show after showing the splash activity. Then the app runs normally with test ads. The Main Activity code is shown below:

````
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.ads.consent.*;
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentForm;
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentFormListener;
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInfoUpdateListener;
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInformation;
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentStatus;
import com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.setAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled;
import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private AdView mAdView;
    private ConsentForm form;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        displayConsentForm();

        ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(this);
        String[] publisherIDs = {"pub-8757875504565304", "173696027825328"};

        consentInformation.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        // Geography appears as in EEA for test devices.
        ConsentInformation.getInstance(this).
                setDebugGeography(DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA);
// Geography appears as not in EEA for debug devices.
        ConsentInformation.getInstance(this).
                setDebugGeography(DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_NOT_EEA);

        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIDs, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
                // User's consent status successfully updated.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {
                // User's consent status failed to update.
            }
        });


        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {


                mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adviewBanner);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        });

    }

    private void displayConsentForm() {


        URL privacyUrl = null;
        try {

            privacyUrl = new URL("https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/57789951");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle error.
        }
        // Consent form loaded successfully.
        // Consent form was displayed.
        // Consent form was closed.
        // Consent form error.

        form = new ConsentForm.Builder(MainActivity.this, privacyUrl)
                .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                        // Consent form loaded successfully.


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                        // Consent form was displayed.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormClosed(
                            ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                        // Consent form was closed.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                        // Consent form error.
                    }
                })
                .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withAdFreeOption()
                .build();

        form.load();
        form.show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.app_options, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        //Handle item selection
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.home) {
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.Paperboard) {
            Intent intentPaperboard = new Intent(this, PaperboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentPaperboard);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.Cardboard) {
            Intent intentCardboard = new Intent(this, CardboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentCardboard);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.stencils) {
            Intent stencilIntent = new Intent(this, EmailStencilsExterior.class);
            startActivity(stencilIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}```

I've imported the consent sdk 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'

I have a mediation group set up with just Facebook Audience Network as the only other ad source. Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >


        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>

        <!-- Delay app measurement until MobileAds.initialize() is called. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT"
            android:value="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-8757875504565304~1889665505" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name=".MediaPlayerActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CardboardActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PaperboardActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".EmailStencilsExterior">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>```

The logcat shows the following message after running the app:

2021-06-27 14:35:21.509 23977-23977/com.gcps.classicsplitlevel I/ConsentInformation: This request is sent from a test device.

I don't know why the consent form doesn't show after app launch. I hope I've provided enough info to assess the problem. Thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

Move *form.show()* under *public void onConsentFormLoaded()* like this:

```
@Override
public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
   // Consent form loaded successfully.
   form.show();
}
```

Comment: maybe you meant form.show()

Comment: You're right @nikolayandr. I edited the asnwer.